# Linking shapes to slides using text search in Google Slides script

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Trying to link shapes to slides the same way it's done with images.
[image]
[image]

.

.

Reason for this request is linking images seems much harder in terms of locating the exact one to be linked.

Have realized it might be best to link shapes through match/search text then insert the images after.

Codes attempted though please ignore if completely irrelevent.

```
function myFunction(){
    var searchText = "IMAGE1";

  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[4];
  

  // 2. Replace the shape which has the text of "searchText" with the image of "imageUrl".
  slide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
    if (s.getText().asString().toLocaleUpperCase().includes(searchText.toLocaleUpperCase())) {
      s.setLinkSlide('INSERT_SLIDE_LINK');
      
      }
  }
  )
}
```

[Slides Example](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1p-jWnirEjPh2UeJiQyVDOsQFDV6FtfxW6DQXwfOBWXI/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and your showing script, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, I too apologies for not being very clear. Same as linking images to a slide - would like to try linking a shape with text. Please see question again - hopefully easier to understand. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that I understood your question. So, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to link the shape to a slide by searching the text in the shape on Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

`setLinkSlide` can use Slides Object. I thought that this might be able to be used.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const obj = { text1: 3, text2: 3, text3: 4, text4: 5, text5: 4, text6: 3 }; // This is from your showing sample image.

  const slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides.forEach(s => {
    s.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
      const t = obj[shape.getText().asString().toLowerCase().trim()];
      if (t) {
        shape.setLinkSlide(slides[t - 1]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Google Slides. When you change this, please modify `obj`. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [setLinkSlide(slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#setlinkslideslide)

Comment: @SCTJ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

If I've understood your post correctly, these are your goals:

1. Check the text on each of the `shapes` in your slides
2. See if the current text `shape` matches the current `searchText` value
3. If `true`, link a dedicated slide to the current `shape`.

### Sample Tweaked Script

```
function sample() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides();

  //Define the 'searchText' value & it's dedicated slide to be linked
  var find = {
    search: [["Text1", slide[1]],
             ["Text2", slide[2]],
             ["Text3", slide[3]]]
  };

  find.search.forEach(d => {
    let searchText = d[0];
    let linkSlide = d[1];
    slide[0].getShapes().forEach(s => {
      s.getText().asString().trim().toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase() ? s.setLinkSlide(linkSlide) : null;
    });
  })
}
```